Joint Central Moments of Bivariate Exponential Distribution
While doing a study on the growth metrics RRRGR (Reverse of Relative of Relative Growth Curve), I'm stuck on the exact distribution of the growth metrics $ W_{ji} = ln \left( \dfrac{R_{ji} (t)}{R_{ji} (t+1)} \right) $ [$ R_{ji}(t) $ stands for the RGR (Relative Growth Rate) growth metric by Fisher] where RGR follows Exponential Distribution.
I need the mixed central moment of bivariate exponential distribution $ (\mu_{rs}) $ of two exponential variables X and Y, who are not independent. More specifically, a recurrence relation of the moments like that of Bivariate Normal Distribution (If (X, Y) follows $ N(\theta_1, \theta_2, {\sigma_1}^2, {\sigma_2}^2, \rho) $, then $ \mu_{rs} = (r + s - 1) \rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}\mu_{r-1, s-1} + (r-1)(s-1)(1 - \rho^2) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \mu_{r-2,s-2} $). I provided the Bivariate Normal mixed moments recursion relation in case anyone stumbles over here while in search of a different question in future.
Now can someone help me with the moments or recursion relation of joint moments of Bivariate Exponential distribution?

What is your definition of a 'bivariate exponential law?

@LetacGérard nothing is specified honestly, which has confused me as well. Which one would you suggest to use?

Difficult to answer to the  question 'which question should I raise?' If $(X,Y)$ is a pair of dependent standard exponential random variables, then the law of $(U,V)=(e^{-X},e^{-Y})$ is a copula, and the choice of one of them is infinite and depends of your aims, needs, motivations, easyness of computation.
